# Which cells release inflammatory mediators?

Tags: immunology

Wikipedia says

> **Inflammation is stimulated by chemical factors released by injured cells** and serves to establish a physical barrier against the spread of infection, and to promote healing of any damaged tissue following the clearance of pathogens.

then it mentions

> The process of acute inflammation is initiated by cells already present in all tissues, mainly resident macrophages, dendritic cells, histiocytes, Kupffer cells, and mastocytes. These cells present receptors contained on the surface or within the cell, named pattern recognition receptors (PRRs), which recognize molecules that are broadly shared by pathogens but distinguishable from host molecules, collectively referred to as pathogen-associated molecular patterns (PAMPs). At the onset of an infection, burn, or other injuries, **these cells undergo activation** (one of their PRRs recognizes a PAMP) **and release inflammatory mediators** responsible for the clinical signs of inflammation.

From this we can clearly deduce that the inflammatory mediators are released by Pattern recongintion receptor producing cells. But while studing this topic from different sources some, books on nursing and Pharmacy. They keep repeating that inflammatory mediators are released by injured cells.

What is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several kinds of inflammatory mediators. You can broadly classify them as cytokines (including interferons) and chemokines.

Cells which sense antigens (or pathogen associated molecular patterns) do secrete cytokines, as you said but infected cells also secrete some cytokines like [interferons- α and β](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interferon_type_I). Infected/injured cells also secrete chemokines that attract leukocytes to the site of infection/injury ([Saiman and Freidman, 2012](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3379724/)).